# Helper functions in airflow

Tags: python, airflow

Where should be placed helper functions in airflow? Should it be added in the plugin directory? I'm going to have some repeatable code for my ETL jobs like so:

```
#create a sub dag containing DROP -> CREATE -> INSERT 
sub_create_dag = DAG('%s.%s' % (parent_dag_name, child_dag_name), default_args=args)
pg_drop = DropPostgresOperator(task_id='drop_{}'.format(table), sql="", params={'schema': schema, 'table': table}, postgres_conn_id=args['connection_id'], autocommit=True, dag=sub_create_dag)
pg_create = PostgresOperator(task_id='create_{}'.format(table), sql='{sql_path}/create_{name}.sql'.format(sql_path=sql_path, name=table), postgres_conn_id=args['connection_id'], autocommit=True, dag=sub_create_dag)
pg_insert = PostgresOperator(task_id='insert_{}'.format(table), sql='{sql_path}/insert_{name}.sql'.format(sql_path=sql_path, name=table), postgres_conn_id=args['connection_id'], autocommit=True, dag=sub_create_dag)
pg_drop >> pg_create >> pg_insert
return dag
```

The issue is that I'm going to have errors like:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 187, in get_source   
raise TemplateNotFound(template)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have used a combination of both. We have implemented the independent tasks as custom operators in the plugin folder, while small functions as just python functions in the DAG folder itself.
Regarding error, it is because the jinja could not find the templates folder. This error shouldn't pop up if you implement the helper functions in either DAG or plugins folder.